# Using CSS to position an image above the following <div>

Tags: html, css, layout, position

I am trying to achieve the layout as shown in the attached image.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I currently have the following HTML markup (the CSS for "white-bg" is simply done by a line of background-color and the gray colour of the bottom part is by setting the background-color of the body):

```
<body class="gray-bg">
<section class="white-bg">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">Title</h2>
        <img class="feature-image" src="./images/image.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>Body text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

I wonder what I need for .feature-image in my CSS in order to achieve the layout I want to have?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since I don't have your CSS library, how does it show up like that? Have you tried moving the image to a separate div row?

Comment: Sorry.  I should clarify I am using Bootstrap 3 as my backbone CSS library.  Let me update my question to include this information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on a mobile device so I can't check my answer but giving your gray_bg div a negative top margin should do the trick. Like this margin-top: -10px;
Also. You might have to put your bottom div inside a class of container-fluid

Ok here is a working example

```css
.white-bg {
  background-color: white;
  }

.feature-image {
 background-color: lightgray;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  }
.gray-bg {
  background-color: gray;
  }
```

```html
<body class="gray-bg">
  <head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
<section class="white-bg">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="text-center">Title</h2>
        <img class="feature-image" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnL5-GO2muNIeI97gaUNYWdyzB5tLozHkacW4O8Q0TNWQC35ns" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>Body text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, HTMLNoob!  Yes your solution works but after taking a closer look at the structure of my current HTML file, I have to admit I was inaccurate in my original question.  The gray-bg div was indeed not a gray-bg div.  The gray background was indeed from the <body> and therefore having a negative margin-top would not move the gray up.  Let me revise my original question to clarify this.  Hopefully you will have some suggestions for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: ok @topgun200204 so you want your bottom div to move up instead of the image to move down?

Comment: I indeed want the image to move down as the bottom is the body and cannot be moved up or down per se.

Comment: Ok I will edit my answer accordingly.  This may take a bit of experimentation

Comment: Thank you very much, HTMLNoob!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following CSS:

```
.col-lg-12{
    position:relative;
    top:-300px;
}
```

However, I suggest adding another class, let's say "**up**" to the **col-lg-12** containing the image and the title and stylize **.up** because it's usually not a good idea to overwrite bootstrap classes and such.

Answer (score 0):

Add your title, image and body text all into the one div, row, section. Instead of separating your content across two sections to cater for the background colour, use a gradient background instead and apply that to the section or body of your document.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/